# Is it possible to use an nvme slot to get a thunderbolt port (on a Lenovo ThinkPad E560)

Tags: thinkpad

My Lenovo ThinkPad E560 (Intel Core i5-6210U, 16Gb DDR3L-PC312800S) has an NVMe slot specifically for my network card.

I don't really care how it looks, but I need an expansion for Thunderbolt 3 or 4 (trying to get an eGPU) that can support both the USB-C (Thunderbolt) ports and my network card using the PCI lane for the NVMe slot. I don't know what it is called or what to Google even after some extensive internet searching. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Since my laptop is relatively old, I don't know if the NVMe slot for the network card takes up a PCI lane or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> has an NVMe slot specifically for my network card.

That's definitely not an "NVMe slot" then, as NVMe is a *storage* protocol, *not* a generic expansion interface – PCI Express is the actual underlying interface. What's common between network cards and NVMe storage cards is the **M.2** slot shape, which provides access to PCIe lanes (among other things).

There are [several types ("keys")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2#Form_factors_and_keying) of M.2 slots, which have a various mix of PCI-Express lanes, SATA lanes, USB lanes, and other connections. For example, "M"-keyed slots for SSDs have SATA and 4×PCIe lanes.

> EDIT: Since my laptop is relatively old, I don't know if the NVMe slot for the network card takes up a PCI lane or not.

It definitely does; although network cards are not NVMe, but both network cards *and* NVMe storage cards generally use PCI Express.

However, a Wi-Fi + Bluetooth network card would probably use PCIe *and* USB, the latter being for the Bluetooth controller (while the Wi-Fi interface would be on PCIe). This would be an "E"-keyed M.2 slot, I believe.

(So although Wi-Fi and NVMe cards are both just PCIe devices, their slots are probably not interchangeable because of different M.2 pinouts.)

> need an expansion for Thunderbolt 3 or 4 (trying to get an eGPU) that can support both the USB-C (Thunderbolt) ports and my network card using the PCI lane for the NVMe slot

I am not sure whether such a thing exists in the M.2 form factor.

An add-on card cannot simply change the existing USB-C ports of your laptop into Thunderbolt ports – they are not *wired* for that to be possible – it would need to provide its own ports, and it can't really do that in a laptop.

Full-size PCIe cards with stand-alone Thunderbolt controllers [do exist](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08BC11XW8) (there's one for TB 4 as well), but that's because a PCIe card has a *backplate* to put the actual ports in. Laptop M.2 slots don't have that; such a card, if it existed, would need to have a ribbon cable and a breakout board dangling out of your laptop.

(Now there are direct [break-outs](http://www.bplus.com.tw/ExtenderBoard/P14S-P14F.html) from M.2 to a full-size PCIe slot if you do not mind a ribbon cable dangling out of your laptop, but those are usually for B/M-keyed "SSD" slots, and frankly are a bit questionable in the first place and much less likely to work with newer PCIe generations; e.g. this particular one is only designed for "PCI Express version 1.1 (2.5 Gbps)" and is very unlikely to handle your GPU's PCIe 5.0 connection without major signal degradation.)

Also, it seems to me that "network card" M.2 slots might not offer sufficient PCIe lanes for a decent GPU in the first place. While a M-keyed "SSD" slot offers 4× which might be acceptable, an E-keyed "Wi-Fi" slot has even less.

Comment: Just to clarify, M.2 is the slot type? Not NVMe? I guess I got confused, haha...

Comment: Yes, you're confused. M.2 is just the slot type. NVMe - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVM_Express - typically comes in a package with M.2 connector but also many others as explained in the Wikipedia link. This answer explains everything you should know, especially that what you want isn't really doable. You should accept the answer.